# Unable to get the id or value of the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-selectors

This is the Html code:

```
<div class="ribbon-fav" id="fav_id">
            <%- if user_signed_in? %>
                    <%- unless current_user.favorite_texts.exists?(id: text.id) -%>
                            <%= link_to image_tag("fav-hrt.png", size: "20x18", alt: "Add Favorite", title: " Add Favorite "), :id => 'fav_id_002' %>
                    <%- else -%>
                            <%= link_to image_tag("favd-hrt.png", size: "20x18", alt: "Remove from Favorites", title: " Remove from Favorites "), :id => 'fav_id_001' %>
                    <%- end -%>
            <%- else -%>
                    <%= link_to image_tag("fav-hrt.png", size: "20x18", alt: "Add Favorite", title: " Add Favorite "), favorite_texts_path(text_id: text.id), method: :post, :'data-turbolinks-action' => 'replace' %>
            <%- end -%>
```

Below is the Javascript

```
console.log("favorite_add_remove.js loaded");

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("called function");
    $("#fav_id a").on("click", function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        //var value = $(this).val();
        console.log(e.target.id);
        //console.log(value);
    });
    //f1();
})
```

I am unable to get the id or value of the link clicked. How do I get the id of the clicked element? Please help, thanks.

Comment: have you tried `e.target.id`? you are calling function inside another function this is bad. put click event outside of `f1()`

Comment: Add rendered html also

Comment: No need to write function `f1()`. Put all your code out of that.

Comment: as per comments removed the f1() function, still not working

Comment: Those who have downvoted please dont downvote before answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the fiddle example. this might help you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".test").click(function(){
  var clickedId = this.id; 
  alert(this.id);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="surya1" class="test">asda</a>
<a href="#" id="surya2" class="test">asd</a>
<a href="#" id="surya3" class="test">asdasd</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hu7r7hsu/

All you have to do is set a same class for all the anchor tags and after making it common follow the example of below code.

```
$(".linkClass").on("click", function() {
  var clickedId = this.id;
}
```

Comment: The way suggested by is not working. As the link we are trying to click is inside an if clause. I am not sure, but most probably we will not be able to directly select that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('#fav_id').on('click', 'a', function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: it is giving `udefined`. Is something has to be done with the if clause? Cause the link we are trying to click is inside the if clause.

Comment: can you add rendered html as well?

Answer (score 0):

This made it work, had to change a little bit in the html.

```
<div class="ribbon-fav" id="fav_id">
            <%- if user_signed_in? %>
                    <%- unless current_user.favorite_texts.exists?(id: text.id) -%>
                            <%= link_to image_tag("fav-hrt.png", size: "20x18", alt: "Add Favorite", title: " Add Favorite ", :id => 'fav_id_002') %>
                    <%- else -%>
                            <%= link_to image_tag("favd-hrt.png", size: "20x18", alt: "Remove from Favorites", title: " Remove from Favorites ", :id => 'fav_id_001') %>
                    <%- end -%>
            <%- else -%>
                    <%= link_to image_tag("fav-hrt.png", size: "20x18", alt: "Add Favorite", title: " Add Favorite "), favorite_texts_path(text_id: text.id), method: :post, :'data-turbolinks-action' => 'replace' %>
            <%- end -%>
        </div>
```

Removed the `id` from the link tag and added it to the `img` tag.

And the Javascript as below:

```
console.log("favorite_add_remove.js loaded");

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("called function");
    $("#fav_id a").on("click", function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        var imgIdVal = $('img', this).attr('id');
        console.log(imgIdVal);
    });
})
```

This gave the output as `fav_id_002`;